# Function 'replace' doesn't seem to work when iterating an array of lines

Tags: python, parsing, replace, split

I am trying to parse an array of lines via `split`, `replace` and `join`.

My ultimate goal is to take a given piece of code (in Solidity for all it matters), and prepend an underscore to each function argument name.

Here is a minimized version of my code (only what's imperative for the question at hand):

```
def checkLine(line):
    return any([line.startswith('    '+word) for word in ['function','constructor','event']])

def checkWord(word):
    return any([word.startswith(x) for x in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']) and any([word.endswith(x) for x in ',);'])

def parseFile(fileName):
    fileDesc = open(fileName, 'r')
    lines = fileDesc.read().split('\n')
    fileDesc.close()

    for n in range(len(lines)):
        if checkLine(lines[n]):
            for word in lines[n].split(' '):
                if checkWord(word):
                    lines[n] = lines[n].replace(word,'_'+word)
                    if lines[n].endswith('{'):
                        m = n+1
                        while not lines[m].endswith('}'):
                            lines[m] = lines[m].replace(word,'_'+word)
                            m += 1

    fileDesc = open(fileName, 'w')
    fileDesc.write('\n'.join(lines))
    fileDesc.close()
```

And here is the problem that I've been banging my head with for hours:

The line `lines[n] = lines[n].replace(word,'_'+word)` does the job just fine.

But the line `lines[m] = lines[m].replace(word,'_'+word)` doesn't have any effect.

So I am able to change the argument names in the function header, but not in the function body.

Here is a sample input file:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

import "./interfaces/IMyContract.sol";

/**
 * @title My Contract.
 */
contract MyContract is IMyContract {
    string public constant version = "1.0.0";

    mapping(bytes32 => address) private something;

    event Event(bytes32 indexed var1, address indexed var2);

    /**
     * @dev ...
     * @param var3 ...
     * @param var4 ...
     */
    constructor(bytes32[] memory var3, address[] var4) public {
        uint256 length = var3.length;
        require(length == var4.length);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            require(uint256(something[var3[i]]) == 0);
            something[var3[i]] = var4[i];
            emit Event(var3[i], var4[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev ...
     * @param var5 ...
     */
    function get(bytes32 var5) external view returns (address) {
        return something[var5];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that after your `checkWord` test, you need to strip off the trailing parentheses, colon, etc... or the replacement doesn't work for the rest of the tokens

Use `rstrip` to remove those chars, then the replacement works.

```
    for word in lines[n].split(' '):
        if checkWord(word):
            word = word.rstrip(',);')
```

sample output:

```
constructor(bytes32[] memory _var3, address[] _var4) public {
    uint256 length = _var3.length;
    require(length == _var4.length);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        require(uint256(something[_var3[i]]) == 0);
```

Also change `lines[m].replace(word,"_"+word)` by a more robust word-replacement method like word-boundary replacement regex, because if other variables *start* by the same string, they'll be replaced as well.

```
>>> s = "hello var4 this is var41"
>>> s.replace("var4",'_var4')
'hello _var4 this is _var41'   # wrong!
import re
>>> re.sub(r"\b({})\b".format("var4"),r"_\1",s)
'hello _var4 this is var41'  # correct
```

Your code works on generated code, but relies heavily on the fact that parameters are immediately followed by some chars, and not spaces. Manual edit of the file may break your parsing.

Comment: That regex boundary is really cool. Takes quite a bit of string gymnastics to get around that otherwise

Comment: yeah, thanks. without regex that can become pretty awful

Answer (score 0):

To read a file, it is best to use `with` to avoid `open` and `close` needing to be called explicitly:

```
with open(myfile) as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()
```

You can leave out the `'r'` flag, as files will be automatically be opened in read mode.

From here, you can see if one of your event-types is in the line using a `for` loop like so:

```
f_types = ['Event', 'constructor', 'function']

for line in lines:
    for f in f_types:
        if f in line:
            break
    else:
         continue
```

The `else` here is checking that the iteration over `f_types` concluded (`break` didn't happen), so we will skip the lines that don't have any notable events (`f_types`)

Next, we can use the following regex pattern to find all of our arguments:

```
res = re.findall('\((.*?)\)', line)
# for the line constructor(bytes32[] memory var3, address[] var4)
# this returns ['bytes32[] memory var3, address[] var4']

# Now we want to split the line on commas to give each declaration and
# grab the last statement because we don't care about anything but the name
args = [x.split()[-1] for x in res[0].split(',')]
```

Now to store all of that, the whole script becomes this:

```
f_types = ['Event', 'constructor', 'function']
allargs = [] # to store all of our replace calls at the end

with open(myfile) as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

for line in lines:
    for f in f_types:
        if f in line:
            break
    else:
         continue

    in_parens = re.findall('\w+\((.*?)\)', line)[0]
    args = [x.split()[-1] for x in in_parens.split(',')

    allargs.extend(args)
```

After running that, `allargs` will look like:

```
# ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var3[i]', 'var4[i]', 'var5']
```

Now, borrowing from @Jean's answer above, I'm not too worried about the duplicated `var3` and `var4` because we've established those boundaries on the string:

```
whole_file = '\n'.join(lines)

for arg in allargs:
    whole_file = re.sub(r"\b(%s)\b" % arg, r'_\1', whole_file)
```

And now, your file looks like

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

import "./interfaces/IMyContract.sol";

/**
 * @title My Contract.
 */
contract MyContract is IMyContract {
    string public constant version = "1.0.0";

    mapping(bytes32 => address) private something;

    event Event(bytes32 indexed _var1, address indexed _var2);

    /**
     * @dev ...
     * @param _var3 ...
     * @param _var4 ...
     */
    constructor(bytes32[] memory _var3, address[] _var4) public {
        uint256 length = _var3.length;
        require(length == _var4.length);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            require(uint256(something[_var3[i]]) == 0);
            something[_var3[i]] = _var4[i];
            emit Event(_var3[i], _var4[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev ...
     * @param _var5 ...
     */
    function get(bytes32 _var5) external view returns (address) {
        return something[_var5];
    }
}
```